# How to find camera capture resolutions using c#?

Tags: c#

I need to know ,how to find camera capture resolutons using c#.

Comment: I'm afraid camera interaction is going to drag you into pInvoke unless you find some library on the net.

Comment: Nobody has answered your question because you haven't provided enough information. What sort of technology are you using, and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?